# Barra de búsqueda, sería conveniente que autocompletara etiquetas al detectar corchete ("[") de apertura

Tags: característica-nueva, etiquetas

Considero conveniente la barra de búsqueda de SO sea capaz de sugerir etiquetas al detectar como primer caracter el símbolo "[". No es por pereza al escribir, daría la idea de las ya existentes claro.

Comment: Todas las etiquetas estan en su propia seccion. Igual este cambio que pedis, es para toda la red, asi que deberias pedirlo en Stack Exchange...

Comment: @gbianchi, gracias. entonces paso a Exchange!!

Comment: La marcaron como duplicado... De una pregunta de hace **11** años :facepalm:

Comment: La búsqueda en SO tiene problemas más serios que resolver.

Comment: @CandidMoe plantéelos en Stack Exchange y seguro le darán respuesta.

Comment: @Francisco. La falta de emojis me impide deducir la intención de tu comentario.

Comment: @CandidMoe me disculpo con usted, mi intención es no ofender a nadie y mucho menos recibir ofensas existan o no emojis, el sitio no es para eso; de hecho no me considero una persona muy productiva en este espacio pero sí lo tengo muy en cuenta por la ayuda que he recibido de parte de los integrantes. Por muy sencillo que sea mi planteamiento se puede o no tener en cuenta.